# Google Maps position with postal codes

Tags: google-map, google

Is it possible to show a pin on google map for a postal code?
I have only the country name, state name and city name with postal code. Is it possible to show a pin for such postal code? Or do we need to have latitude and longitude?

Comment: I am pretty sure that those question is google api question, not salesforce. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147803/how-to-use-zip-code-instead-lat-and-lng-in-google-maps-api. Or put more details to make it more SF specific

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without latitude and longitude. You can use the query parameter `q` for the address with country name, state name, city name with postal code.

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=<address>
```

Example:-

http://maps.google.com/?q=700 Columbus Avenue, New York, NY 10025, United States

[image]